# What can I do during a typhoon/blizzard?

Tags: story-of-seasons-trio-of-towns

During extreme weather... stamina usage is increased pretty dramatically, as well as literally everything in all 3 towns being closed.

How can I make use of an extreme weather day? Or is it better to just go right back to bed as crops do get automatically watered at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you have livestock, just tend to them as usual.

If it's past three days for the mining at Westown, then mine (bring food that'll recover stamina).

If you already have the cellar, then do underground farming.

You could also use this time as an opportunity to review things in the Farm Report.

Take note that crops (trees or root crops) will have a decreased level in one of their attributes (Juiciness, Aroma, Sweetness, etc) by the next day. So if your crops reached the 100% in, for example, Juiciness, it would most likely be 96% by the next harvest period if you hadn't remedied it with fertiliser assuming you use one.